# Accordion opens, but not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next problem.

Accordion is opening on click, but when I click it again to close, it doesn't.

my HTML markup:

```
<div class="title">

    <a href="#">Heading</a>

</div>

<div class="content">

    <li><p>Content</p></li>

</div>

</section>
```

my javascript code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('.accordion').on('click', '.title', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.accordion .active').next().slideUp('normal');
        $(this).siblings('.accordion .title').removeClass("active");

        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') === true) {
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
    $('.accordion .content').hide();
    $('.accordion .active').next().slideDown('normal');
})();
```

Comment: Can you provide your html markup?

Comment: Can you put it in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and using `this` inside the function (this is the clicked item).

Code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('.accordion').on('click', '.title', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle('normal');
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
    $('.accordion .content').hide();
    $('.accordion .active').next().slideDown('normal');
})();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/9MSAC/1

### UPDATE

To have only one element opened at a time, you can previously close them all.

Code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('.accordion').on('click', '.title', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.title').not($(this)).siblings('.content').slideUp('normal');
        $('.title').not($(this)).removeClass("active");
        $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle('normal');
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
    $('.accordion .content').hide();
    $('.accordion .active').next().slideDown('normal');
})();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/9MSAC/8/

Comment: How make it work with multiple headings? what if I have 2 or 3 headings?

Comment: @user2504339 it will work too, by using this and HTML nesting/siblins is ready, check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/9MSAC/1/

Comment: If first heading is active, when I click second heading, first doesn't close.. Please help with this. Thank you very much I am almost there.

Comment: @user2504339 check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/NYgp3/ I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks Irvin & Suresh. Really appreciate your help guys. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="faqContainerUL">
            <li>
                &nbsp;How do I add a device?
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                &nbsp;What is device Group and how does it differ from Location?
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                </p>
            </li>
```

Javascript

```
$.each($('ul.faqContainerUL li'), function (index, elem) {
$(elem).on('click', function () {
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
});
});
```

Fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/dh25L/

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward I intented to make it more simpler.Wanted to show him to do an accordion in a simple way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Irvin Dominin aka Edward for giving the answer. I am giving updated answer, As "user2504339" want to hide other accordion on click.

```
  (function () {
'use strict';
$('.accordion').on('click', '.title', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
    {                         $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle('normal');
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
    else
    {
    $('.accordion .content').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle('normal');
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
});
$('.accordion .content').hide();
$('.accordion .active').next().slideDown('normal');
})();
```

[**Updated JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9MSAC/7/)

Comment: It is hiding the other accordions but first opened accordion is not closing now.